# Magento 2 on localhost not loading images of products and logo when on different langugage

Tags: php, magento

I have a magento 2.2 instalation on localhost
Windows 10
PHP 7.1.8

I have chosen the default langugage to be Bulgarian when installing. 
When I open a product page it does not find the image. The logo is not loaded too. But when I switch the locale from the admin panel to English (United States) everything loads fine.
I have tried many things like running `php bin/magento setup:static-content`, deleting directories etc. None of them worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate static content separately. For each locale. Dunno why it can't collect all locales by itself but I always deploy them separately to avoid any problems.

Try this line below.

**rm -rf pub/static/frontend/* pub/static/adminhtml/* generated/*  var/view_prepocessed/*; php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US; php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy bg_BG; php bin/magento cache:clean;**